# Get next lexicographic character

Tags: java, methods, char, lexicographic

Is there a method of java characters that will return the next character in lexicographical order?

```
char x = 'a'.next();
```

`'a'.next()` would return `b`. `'b'.next()` would return `c`. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char x = 'a';
System.out.println(++x);
```

Output: `b`

I hope this is enough as a hint.

Basically, just increase the ASCII code of `char` variable to get the next char.

And yes, `ASCII` code is basically just an integer. (Try doing `System.out.println((int) 'a');` and you will get output as `97`, which is the ASCII value for char `a`). Similarly, every char has some ASCII value.

Comment: Just to clarify, the ASCII code is an integer value - in case it doesn't make sense to perform arithmetic on a char data type. Also, 'A' will have a different int ASCII code than 'a'.